# Get the value of the first row and first column of a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a file that has the values:

```
abc1:def1:xyz1
abc2:def2:xyz2
```

Now I want these values `abc1` and `abc2` from the file inside 2 different variables, lets say `var1 = abc1` and `var2=abc2`.
I want to do this is python. Till now the code that I have is:

```
with open(self.file_path, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line_data = line.split(':')[0]
        print(line_data)
```

But this line data prints:

```
abc1
abc2
```

How can I modify my code to store`abc1` and `abc2` values in different variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split by `:` and save the results in a `list` then get the values in the variables by indexing:

list.txt:

```
abc1:def1:xyz1
abc2:def2:xyz2
```

Hence:

```
res = []
with open("list.txt", 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line_data = line.split(':')[0]
        res.append(line_data)

var1 = res[0]
var2 = res[1]

print(var1)
print(var2)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
abc1
abc2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
with open("file.txt", 'r') as fp: # my file name is "file.txt"
        for line in fp:
            count+=1
            line_data = line.split(':')[0]
            print("var"+str(count),"=",line_data)
```

Comment: the counter is to increment var